# show div based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, php, html, textbox

I have a input field that gets it value from a db lets say the value is M,K,H,J,V or G depending on the value it needs to open the div with aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee or fff as text.

The code that is displayed on the page is as followed i left out the retrieval part from the db that part is working (the input box shows M,K,H,J,V or G depending on the id.)

```
echo "<input type='text' name='periode' id='periode' data-related-item='" .$row['periode']. "' value='" .$row['periode']. "'>";
echo "<div class='hidden'><div id='M'>aaa</div></div>";
echo "<div class='hidden'><div id='K'>bbb</div></div>";
echo "<div class='hidden'><div id='H'>ccc</div></div>";
echo "<div class='hidden'><div id='J'>ddd</div></div>";
echo "<div class='hidden'><div id='V'>eee</div></div>";
echo "<div class='hidden'><div id='G'>fff</div></div>";
```

When i check the source code in developer mode it shows that the data-related-item part is correctly retrieved from the db:

```
<input type="text" name="periode" id="periode" data-related-item="M" value="M">
```

I want to use the following JS but i need to change it to work with textboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function evaluate1(){
var item = $(this);
var relatedItem = $("#" + item.attr("data-related-item")).parent();

if(item.is(":checked")){
    relatedItem.fadeIn();
}else{
    relatedItem.fadeOut();   
}
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluate1).each(evaluate1);
</script>
```

The simplest approach is offcourse changing:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluate1).each(evaluate1);
```

into

```
$('input[type="textbox"]').click(evaluate1).each(evaluate1);
```

But what do i need to do with:

```
if(item.is(":checked")){
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

I tried the following but it aint working.

```
if(item.is("M||K||H||J||V||G")){
```

**SOLUTION BY ROBERT ROZAS**

The solution is in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dXTtz/7/

Comment: Why don't you make an ajax call and load in the output you want into a div according to the string you entered?

Comment: I dont know how to do the ajax call and i am not entering a string. the values M,K,H,J,V or G are retrieved from DB i am not filling it in.

Comment: I think your question is a little wrong then? So you want checkboxes/dropdown/..? to be filled and onclick of those, you want a div with specified text?

Comment: the values M,K,H,J,V or G are retrieved from DB and inserted into an textbox. now i want a js code that shows div id M when the textbox is M or show div id J when textbox is J. my question becomes complicated because i am trying to do this with a piece of code that i picked from the internet. i cant just ask someone to write the code for me that would be the easiest way but also annoying for all the SO contributors.

Comment: Ok, you just lost me completely: The only thing I can say is: 1. You create a div according to the value you got from your DB, or create something like a dropdown and then create the div according, but If you load in all data in the textbox, you can't do anything with it?

Comment: Let me try to ask it in another way maybe this makes it clear. I have 6 divs those divs have the following ids M,K,H,J,V or G. I want to show div M when the textbox value is M and hide all others. PS Thanks for helping.

Comment: When textbox value is M show div M and hide div k,h,j,v,g
When textbox value is k show div k and hide div m,h,j,v,g
When textbox value is j show div j and hide div m,k,h,v,g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this code based on the code you provide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#periode").keyup(function(){
 var valor = $("#periode").val();
    $(".hidden").each(function(){
     var hijo = $(this).children().attr('id');   
     if(hijo == valor)
     {
      $(this).removeClass("hidden");
     }
    });
});

});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/dXTtz/2/

This way is working on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/dXTtz/4/

Page load and removing the extra hidden divs: http://jsfiddle.net/dXTtz/5/

Comment: Thank you this is getting very close to what i want. I made a small change. http://jsfiddle.net/dXTtz/3/ How do i need to change the javascript so it works on page load. because the value is not typed in but retrieved from db.

Comment: Thank you for your edit(pageload) this is a brilliant sollution. But when the value is H like in this http://jsfiddle.net/dXTtz/5/ then it shows a lot of white space how can i get rid of that whitespace.

Comment: sorry stupid question my last comment i need to change the css part of course to .hidden{display:none}

Comment: It's because the other div still exists, but are hidden...if this execute on page load...wait i update the answer again ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It is brilliant i don't understand the code but i am trying to figure it out. The main thing is that it works!